# Why do images being sent to a rails gallery model with correct associations not show up?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-4, relationship

I have a gallery that allows people to upload images to a book. My gallery has_many :images and my image belongs_to :gallery. The form for the gallery has a nested form for the image fields and that is rendered inside a book view. I know this works well as I can create the book and associate a gallery and get the id of that gallery that links with the book.

My only issue now is when I create the book and upload images to the gallery inside the book the images do not get added and they are not found attached to the gallery. I did some digging in the rails console and got this:

```
1.9.3-p286 :006 > Book.friendly.find('the-beatles').gallery.images.size
  Book Load (1.2ms)  SELECT "books".* FROM "books" WHERE "books"."slug" = 'the-beatles' ORDER BY "books"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  Gallery Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "galleries".* FROM "galleries" WHERE "galleries"."book_id" = $1 ORDER BY "galleries"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["book_id", 19]]
   (0.6ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "images" WHERE "images"."gallery_id" = $1  [["gallery_id", 10]]
 => 0
```

Breaking it down it basically says its found the books gallery via the gallery_id on the book but has not found the images uploaded to the gallery for that book.

In my models I have:

book.rb

```
belongs_to :author
has_one :gallery

accepts_nested_attributes_for :author
accepts_nested_attributes_for :gallery
```

gallery.rb

```
belongs_to :books
has_many :images
accepts_nested_attributes_for :books
accepts_nested_attributes_for :images, :allow_destroy => true
```

image.rb

```
belongs_to :gallery

    has_attached_file :file, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }, :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png"
    validates_attachment_content_type :file, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
```

In my controllers I have this:

https://gist.github.com/mdunbavan/0dd592b6a8878a664ab0

In my forms it is pretty straightforward and they are all rendering properly and its passing the data for each book and gallery correctly. Its just the images for that gallery that are not being added.

Can anyone see anything glaringly obvious that is wrong with this?

Comment: remove the `size` method from your query and try, `size` is issuing a count query

Comment: I get `=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>`

Comment: did you loop through this object in the view

Comment: yes using `<% @gallery.images.each do |s| %><%= s.file.url %><% end %>` where I get `PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation with OID 16518 does not exist : SELECT "images".* FROM "images"  WHERE "images"."gallery_id" = $1` on the gallery show page for that gallery

Comment: in your rails console try, `Book.friendly.find('the-beatles').gallery.images.length`

Comment: yeah tried that it still outputs `Book Load (35.2ms)  SELECT "books".* FROM "books" WHERE "books"."slug" = 'the-beatles' ORDER BY "books"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  Gallery Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "galleries".* FROM "galleries" WHERE "galleries"."book_id" = $1 ORDER BY "galleries"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["book_id", 19]]
  Image Load (30.2ms)  SELECT "images".* FROM "images" WHERE "images"."gallery_id" = $1  [["gallery_id", 10]]
 => 0`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61373/discussion-between-m-dunbavan-and-pavittar-gill).

Comment: you need to add the `:file` params to your `book_params` method in `BooksController` `gallery_attributes: [image: [:file]]`

Comment: Thats weird it still throws the error